# Index pattern not appearing at Kibana server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, elk

Iam new to stack overflow (so please bear with me) as well as this field (Data analysis especially logs and related stuff). I am using ELK stack for this. following a youtube tutorial and doing the same. I am running total of 2 servers and one CMD console operation for logstash or transferring the data to Kibana (for visualizing after creating its index).

This is my logstash.conf file:
[Logstash.conf code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ISOl.png)

Whereas dataset iam using is "AB_NYC_2019" from kaggle.

The logstash cmd console results as this:
[Logstash CMD console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2JmG.png)


The problem is that after all the above steps and the successful output its not showing the index pattern name.

Comment: Have you checked your data has arrived to Elasticsearch? you can do `GET /_cat/indices`. You are trying to create index pattern in Kibana and it doesn't find your data?